# Copy selected columns from a csv file into a postgres table

Tags: postgresql, copy

In postgres - 
I currently create a table and copy data from a csv file (in the following I create in postgres the exact table, which corresponds to my csv file's table - so the same number of columns) - as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SupEnh_AGK50kb_K27ac (
    EnhancerID_AGK50kb_K27ac character(80) NOT NULL,
    Status_AGK50kb_K27ac character(15) NOT NULL,
    Enrich_D_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Enrich_R_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Enrich_LR_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Span_D_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Span_R_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Span_LR_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Multiplication_D_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Multiplication_R_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Multiplication_LR_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    NumPeaks_D_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    NumPeaks_R_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    NumPeaks_LR_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    PVal_D_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    PVal_R_AGK50kb_K27ac float,
    Pval_lr_AGK50kb_K27ac float,

    CONSTRAINT AGK50kb_27ac_Key PRIMARY KEY (EnhancerID_AGK50kb_K27ac)
);

COPY SupEnh_AGK50kb_K27ac 
FROM 'G:\CarrollLab\EnhancerAnalysis\AGK_K27ac.KeyFile'
WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL 'NULL',HEADER);
```

This procedure works like a charm, but I would like to amend it slightly, so I'll be able to create first a small version of my postgres table - one the holds only the first 5 columns. 
I then want to load directly from my csv file the first 5 columns. 
Is there a way to change slightly the code that I provided here so it'll allow me to do what I'm after (and without using a temporary table that would be created on postgres and will hold all columns) ? 
Thanks a lot,
Roy

Comment: It might be easier to remove columns from the file with some kind of shell script before `COPY`

Comment: Thanks Igor, 
So there is no easy solution in postgres for what I'm after?...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [file_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) foreign data wrapper to access the CSV file, which would allow you to use [SELECT INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html) to query directly from the CSV file into the table. You can then specify exactly the columns you want to keep.

Example: Suppose I have this text file:

```
1,"apple","banana"
2,"pear","orange"
```

and I only want to include the first two columns in my table:

```
-- Do this once only per database, to create the extension and define the fdw server
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER csvfile FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

-- File must be accessible to the backend
-- All columns existing in the file must be present in the FDW table definition
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE mycsv(a integer, b text, c text)
    SERVER csvfile OPTIONS ( filename '/tmp/test.csv', format 'csv');

-- Now we can copy into our actual table
-- ignoring column c
SELECT a,b INTO testtable FROM mycsv;
```

Using SELECT INTO creates the new table for you. An alternative is to create the table beforehand and use `INSERT INTO {table} SELECT {query}`.